# Jackson.dataformat не учитывает регистр

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Нужно получить xml представление объекта в string.
Мой объект

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MessageSysInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MessageSysInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String HostName;
    private String ApplicationName;
    private String AccountId;
    private String EmployeeId;
```

ниже геттеры/сеттеры и конструктор.

Метод для преобразования в строку.

```
String SysInfoXml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(MyObject);
```

xmlMapper.writeValueAsString это библиотека

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
```

Такая проблема.
На выходе должна быть структура

```
<MessageSysInfo>
                <HostName>Test</HostName>                    
                <ApplicationName>Test</ApplicationName>                          
                <AccountId>34307</AccountId>                                    
                <EmployeeId>3628</EmployeeId>                                   
        </MessageSysInfo>
```

но получается

```
<MessageSysInfo>
                <hostName>Test</hostName>                    
                <applicationName>Test</applicationName>                          
                <accountId>34307</accountId>                                    
                <employeeId>3628</employeeId>                                   
        </MessageSysInfo>
```

т.е. метод xmlMapper.writeValueAsString почему то записывает структуру xml в нижнем регистре. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расставьте над переменными аннотации

```
@XmlElement(name = "HostName")
private String hostName;
```